# How to disable past dates in oracle apex with no validation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am disabling past dates in Date Picker in Apex v4.1 by entering in Setting as Minimum Date +0d
But when I am trying to edit and save data next day that field is showing error. Can somebody please help.
[image]

Comment: A validation like this only makes sense on a page that *only* inserts new records. I might consider creating separate forms for creating vs. updating records, although I like Littlefoot's answer better.

Answer (score 1):

I can't view images, but - the way you described it - I'd suggest you to remove `+0d` in Date Picker item and create your own validation whose type is **PL/SQL Function returning error text**; it will check whether item value is equal or larger than `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`, e.g.

```
if :P1_DATE_ITEM < trunc(sysdate) then
   return ('Error - date has to be larger or equal to today''s date');
end if;
```

Then set **validation's server side condition** to e.g. `ITEM IS NULL`, while the "item" is table's primary key item (or - if you're working with the `ROWID` - use it).

Doing so, you'd tell Apex to perform control only for newly created rows (because their primary key column value isn't set yet, nor it has a `ROWID` as row isn't saved into the database). "Old" rows have it and validation won't fire.

Comment: I have more than 50 date picker fields on a page. To enter for fields validation will take more efforts of a Developer. Is not there any other way doing so, it saves data in db for dates which are grayed out on the page?

Comment: You could create a database trigger which would reject invalid values, but you'd still have to name all 50 date columns in it. Perhaps there is an easy way out of it, but I don't know it.